# Pure CSS solution to scroll bar moving centered content

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to center the content on a website. I do not know JavaScript very well and have attempted implementing some of the solutions into my website, but cannot do so. I know CSS much better and was wondering if their was a simple solution to fixing the scroll bar problem.
Any help would be great.

Edit
I have now been learning Javascript and Jquery and discovered things like $(window).height() is doing this a good way to fix it. Is there times when this would not work?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: http://charactercounts.north-staracademy.com/ It just bugs me that the content jumps when you make the window smaller

Comment: I have tried doing everything I can to use the css calc() function, but I have not been able to make anything that makes the content not jump when you make the window smaller

Comment: webpage not available.

Comment: I just clicked on it and it let me in

Comment: It is centered with a margin: auto type centering, but I can't figure out any way to make the scroll bar not make the content jump

Comment: I believe that you want your site to be responsive.

Comment: There is no simple solution for this. But it will be simple if you know responsive design. Try to read about responsive web design. It means that it will look good in every screen size.

Comment: I'll try to copy your code and create a responsive website from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think and I believe that you want responsive design. Here's a demo of it.

### [Full Screen Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tbgnxufb/embedded/result/)

### [HTML and CSS Markups](http://jsfiddle.net/tbgnxufb/)

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: "Arial";
}
.MainHeader{
    background-color:#BFBFBF;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.MainHeaderTitle{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 64px;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: top;
    color:#404040;
}
.MainHeaderLogo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    }
nav{

    overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color: #404040;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: #BFBFBF;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
section ul li a{
    color: #404040;
    text-decoration: none;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
.img-container{
    text-align: center;
}
main{
    width:100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer{
    background-color:#404040;
    color: #BFBFBF;
     overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}
footer a,footer p{
     color: #BFBFBF;
     margin: 5px;
     display: inline-block;

}
.col-3{
    width:25%;
    float:left;

}
```

Comment: I researched responsive web design and I understand what you are trying to tell me, but I am wondering why this example has three scroll bars off to the right.

Comment: because it's only an embedded view from jsfiddle. if you tried to run them locally, scroll bars off to the right won't show. Try copy pasting this and save as html in your local. http://pastebin.com/RPTnALr4